# Copy individual value from one column to other column where conditional is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (call it df).

```
f_col s_col t_col
10   100  0
20   126  0
65   164  0
```

If f_col is over a threshold, I would like to take the matching value located in col2 and copy it to col3.

A desired example of the same dataframe would be (if the threshold is 125):

```
f_col s_col t_col
10   100  0
20   126  126
65   164  164
```

I have tried using masks of f_col like so:

```
mask = df.f_col > 125
column_name = 't_col'
df.loc[mask, column_name] = 0
```

But this induces an error, like so:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: so you mean `df.loc[mask, column_name] = 0
`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the description

Comment: Can not reproduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write with **`loc`** as you suggest :

```
# Module import
import pandas as pd

# Cols names
col_over_treshold = "f_col"
col_to_copy = "s_col"
col_to_update = "t_col"

# Your dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 100, 0],
                   [20, 126, 0],
                   [65, 164, 0]],
                  columns=[col_over_treshold, col_to_copy, col_to_update])

# Your treshold
threshold = 125

# Process
df.loc[df[col_to_copy] > threshold, col_to_update] = df.s_col

#Show results
print(df)
#    f_col  s_col  t_col
# 0     10    100      0
# 1     20    126    126
# 2     65    164    164
```

Or can define a function with a condition that you **apply** to your dataframe :

```
# Your function to apply
def process(data):
    ret = 0
    if data[col_to_copy] > threshold:
        ret = data.s_col
    return ret


# Processing
df[col_to_update] = df.apply(process, axis=1)

#Show results
print(df)
#    f_col  s_col  t_col
# 0     10    100      0
# 1     20    126    126
# 2     65    164    164
```

Comment: With the first approach, can the column names be variables? When I specify the column names as variables an error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 't_col'

Comment: Look at the update. I have just replaces column names by variables in the code. This is what you mean ?

Comment: Partially yes, what if `s_col` in df.s_col was a column name expressed as a variable too? Or is that not allowed?

Comment: No you can't because the variable `col_over_treshold = "f_col"` is a string.